# Perl: using variable as an array element to divide major array into smaller arrays

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a major array `@major` that I want to divide in a given number of minors arrays `@minor` , by setting the number of slices I want (let's say 4 here, but I wish to be able to chose whatever number I want), like this pseudo-code: 
(I know it's not correct, but it sort of gives you the idea)

```
@major = A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J

$slice = 4;
$arraySize = $#array + 1;
$slicesize = $arraySize / $slice;

@minor1 = @major[0..$slicesize]
@minor2 = @major[($slicesize+1)..(2*$slicesize)]
@minor3 = @major[((2*$slicesize)+1)..(3*$slicesize)]
@minor4 = @major[((3*$slicesize)+1)..(4*$slicesize)]
```

The goal here is that I want to be able to change this size of the initial array `@major` and/or the number of slices `$slice` and that all values which set the size of the differents minor arrays (`($slicesize+1)`, `(2*$slicesize)`, and so on).

I know this looks a bit complex but I don't know to expose it in another way.
Do you have any idea about how to achieve this ?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.404/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#part_BLOCK_LIST

Comment: Yep. I'd also suggest for anything complex data-structure-ish then the way to go is make an object.

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure you meant like this, but here it is how I understood your point:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings; use 5.010; 

my @array = ( 'A' .. 'Z' );
my $length_of_slice = $ARGV[0] || 5 ;

while ( @array ) {
  local $" = ', ';
  my @minor = splice @array, 0, $length_of_slice;
  say "@minor";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a complex data structure requirement, my first thought is - use an object. Perl supports object oriented programming, which allows you to do all manner of insanely complicated things like what you're trying to do.

It'd go something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package TestObject;

my @major = qw(A B C D E F G H I J );

sub new {
    my ( $class, $slice_count ) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    if ( defined $slice_count ) { $self->{slice_count} = $slice_count }
    $self->{major} = @major;
    bless( $self, $class );
    return $self;
}


sub get_slices {
    my ( $self, $count ) = @_;
    my @tmp = @major;
    my @array_of_slices;
    for ( 1 .. $count ) {
        my $tmp_arr_ref = ();
        for ( 0 .. ( @major / $count ) ) {
            if ( @tmp ) { push( @$tmp_arr_ref, shift(@tmp) ) };
        }
        push( @array_of_slices, $tmp_arr_ref );
    }
    return (@array_of_slices);
}
```

Called by:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use TestObject;
use Data::Dumper;

my $first = TestObject->new();

my @array_of_refs = $first->get_slices(4);
print Dumper \@array_of_refs;
```

And giving result of:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'A',
            'B',
            'C'
          ],
          [
            'D',
            'E',
            'F'
          ],
          [
            'G',
            'H',
            'I'
          ],
          [
            'J'
          ]
        ];
```

Something like that (you'll have to adjust it a bit to get precisely what you have in mind depending on how you want to handle edge cases/rounding).

Comment: Why are you going on about object oriented when all you're producing in the end is a simple array of arrays?